# How to align controls within column in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my code.

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <label>ID Expire</label>
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-lg-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="TextIDExpire" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <button class="btn btn-default form-control " id="BtnBrowsePhoto"> Browse <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i> </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <button class="btn bg-yellow form-control" id=" btnviewphoto"> View <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i> </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Expected output is

[image]

but i got much white spaces between controls.What i want to do. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

want to center an image , very easy , bootstrap comes with two classes `.center-block` and `text-center` , use the former in the case of your image being a `BLOCK` element eg. add img-responsive class to your `img` makes the `img` a block element , you should know this if you know how to navigate in the web console and see applied styles to an element .

Don't want to use a class , no problem , here is the CSS bootstrap uses , you can make a custome class or write a CSS rule for the element to match the bootstrap class .

```
 // in case your dealing with a block element apply this to the element itself 
.center-block {
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   display:center;
}
// in case your dealing with a inline element apply this to the parent 
.text-center {
   text-align:center
}
```